# How do you load partials from a non-standard directory in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my angular app set up as a bundle within a Symfony app.  Because of this restriction, the directory structure for the angular app is different.  All public resources are symlinked to a static directory, including the partials.  I got the app to load, the controllers fire, but none of the partials load for their specific controllers.  I had this working as a standalone app (outside of Symfony), so I must be missing something with the new configuration.

index.html.twig:
note: the javascript files load just fine- that is the correct asset path

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/groups">Groups</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div ng-view=""></div>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                <div ng-view></div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="bundles/translations/webadmin/app/js/ngroute.js"></script>
    <script src="bundles/translations/webadmin/app/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="bundles/translations/webadmin/app/js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="bundles/translations/webadmin/app/js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="bundles/translations/webadmin/app/js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="bundles/translations/webadmin/app/js/directives.js"></script>

</body>
```

app.js:
note: I tried making templateUrl just partials/ as well

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.filters',
    'myApp.services',
    'myApp.directives',
    'myApp.controllers'
]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/groups', {templateUrl: 'bundles/translations/webadmin/app/partials/groups.html', controller: 'GroupsController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'bundles/translations/webadmin/app/partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeController'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

controllers.js
note: the alerts fire just fine, but the partials don't load...

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    alert('here?');
}])

.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    alert('here2');
}])

.controller('GroupsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // TODO see below
}]);
```

console output:

```
Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) translations:1
Blink is considering rejecting non spec-compliant cross-origin web font requests: https://d3nkxvtkt5c8vi.cloudfront.net/0.4.2/fonts/proxima_nova_light_0.woff. Please use Access-Control-Allow-Origin to make these requests spec-compliant.
```

Any idea what I am missing here?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting for your templates? Also try prepending a `/` to the templateUrl path.

Comment: @MattWay I tried prepending the / to the templateUrl path - no luck.  And there are no JS errors in the console.

Comment: Ok, your console output either infers that the templates are loading correctly but not being shown, or not even being attempted to be loaded at all. The only way I can help you now is if you put together a pastebin (or similar) of a small version of your entire app so that I can run it locally, as routing issues are difficult to diagnose with things like fiddles.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem you have is that `ng-view` is missing from your index markup.

```
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

Without this element, your controllers will load, but have no place to insert your view templates.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

Comment: Can you please list the output from your console when you attempt to load your page.

Comment: I added the console output to the description